# React fetch is not able to contact api on ip

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express

My react-native fetch request is not going through as when it is made, a new object is not created in our mongodb database. The request goes through when made through postman so the express route is working fine.

Here is our react fetch method:

```
const onSignUp = async () => { 
        await fetch('http://myIPv4:5000/api/users', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    'name': name,
                    'email': email,
                    'password': password,
                    'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
                    'userName': userName,
                    'address': address 
                })
            }
        ).then(msg => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(msg))
        })
};
```

Comment: You're combining await/async with promises. I'd update the call to:

let msg = await fetch(...);
console.log(msg);

See if that makes a difference.

Comment: try to pass body without JSON.stringify
 body:{
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
        'userName': userName,
        'address': address 
    }

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For fetching data by **fetch** you must handle that by **async/await** or **then/catch** structure, for example in order to fetching data by async/await , try followings it:

```js
const options  = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'name': name,
        'email': email,
        'password': password,
        'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
        'userName': userName,
        'address': address 
    })
};

const onSignUp = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('http://myIPv4:5000/api/users' , options);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data)
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error);
    };
};
```